# .net core insert using dapper with parameters

Tags: .net-core, dapper

I'm new to using Dapper and I'm a bit lost on following the instructions for an insert statement.

I have the following model:

**User**

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set;}
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And the following controller which is retrieving data from a JSON ajax call (I have tried 3 different ways based on three different answers I've seen.

**Attempt 1** *Error: Incorrect syntax near UserId*

```
public IActionResult UserData([FromBody] User user)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS..."))
    {
        cn.Query<User>(@"INSERT INTO User VALUES UserId = @UserId, UserName = @UserName, Password = @Password", 
        new
        {
            UserId = user.UserId,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Password = user.Password
         });

     return StatusCode(200);
     }
}
```

**Attempt 2** *Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword Table*

```
public IActionResult UserData([FromBody] User user)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS..."))
    {
        cn.Execute(@"INSERT Table(User) VALUES(@UserId, @UserName, @Password)", 
        new
        {
            UserId = user.UserId,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Password = user.Password
         });

     return StatusCode(200);
     }
}
```

**Attempt 3 (Tried using Dapper.Contrib)** *Error: Invalid object name Users (I don't know what this is, Users doesn't exist anywhere as I don't use plurals*

```
public IActionResult UserData([FromBody] User user)
{
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\SQLEXPRESS..."))
    {
        cn.Insert<User>(new User
        {
            UserId = user.UserId,
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Password = user.Password
         });

     return StatusCode(200);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code you provided for Attempt 1, Your SQL insert statement does not look correct!

Also, If you are simply inserting, you may use the `Execute` method. This should work.

If your table has only those 3 columns, you can do this.

```
var q=@"INSERT INTO [User] VALUES (@UserId,@UserName,@Password)";
cn.Execute(q,user);
```

If your table has more columns than what you specified in the insert query, you should explicitly specify the column names(in the order) in the INSERT statement.

```
var q=@"INSERT INTO [User](UserId,UserName,Password) VALUES (@UserId,@UserName,@Password)";
cn.Execute(q,user);
```

Note that the keyword `User` is a reserved keyword. You can wrap it with square brackets to avoid the error.

Use `[User]` instead of `User`.

Reference : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776381(v=sql.105).aspx#BasicSyntax